# Aggregating psycopg2 Errors under a Context Manager

Tags: python

I have various functions which attempt to insert into a PostgreSQL database. In an attempt to remove redundancy for common errors that I was occurring I have created a context manager.

#### Solution

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

import psycopg2


class DomainSpecificException(Exception):
    ...


@contextmanager
def raise_on_insert(table_name: str) -> None:
    try:
        yield
    except psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction:
        raise DomainSpecificException(
            description=(
                f'Failed to insert into: {table_name} because InFailedSqlTransaction, this is usually a sign that the upstream connection has spoiled.'
            )
        )
    except psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation:
        raise DomainSpecificException(
            description=(
                f'Failed to insert into: {table_name} because NotNullViolation for column.'
            )
        )
    except psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation:
        raise DomainSpecificException(
            description=(
                f'Failed to insert into: {table_name} because UniqueViolation for column'
            ),
        )

    except psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation:
        raise DomainSpecificException(
            description=(
                f'Failed to insert into: {table_name} because ForeignKeyViolation for column'
            )
        )
```

#### Usage

```py
with raise_on_insert(table_name='table_1'):
  ...  # Insert into db
```

### Edit

I have improved the code as follows:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

from psycopg2.errors import InFailedSqlTransaction, NotNullViolation, UniqueViolation, ForeignKeyViolation


INSERT_EXCEPTIONS: tuple[Exception, ...] = (
    InFailedSqlTransaction,
    NotNullViolation,
    UniqueViolation,
    ForeignKeyViolation
)


class DomainSpecificException(Exception):
    pass


@contextmanager
def raise_on_insert(table_name: str) -> None:
    try:
        yield
    except INSERT_EXCEPTIONS as err:
        raise DomainSpecificException(description=f'Failed to insert into: {table_name} because {type(err).__name__}')
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two implementations here, one better than the other. Cool.

Kudos on annotating and passing `mypy` lint.
And defining app-specific exceptions is very helpful
to callers who want coarse- or fine-grained try / catches.

---

In the 1st implementation, my chief critique is
[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself),
it just seems a bit chatty. No biggie.

I *do* appreciate that the InFailedSqlTransaction case is
trying hard to be helpful, to offer a **diagnostic** error
that helps some poor maintainer figure out the root cause and the fix.

I still have some minor reservations, but they show up in both implementations.

---

The 2nd implementation is very nice.
Short, sweet, clear code.

Here is one concern.
I don't know the right answer here, I will just voice the concern.
Maybe four exceptions is the right number?
But maybe other bad things can go wrong?
I'm just wondering if psycopg2 maybe offers some umbrella exception
that you would also like to throw in there.

Taking a step back, it's not clear from these source documents
exactly what your error handling objectives are.
The code I'm reading *mostly* seems focused on exposing
details to a handler that's not very far up the call stack
which can maybe recover / ignore / retry when a low-level
bad thing happens, so the high-level business goal still
ends up getting accomplished.
We're missing some review context here.
I would have loved the opportunity to read calling code that has a `try`,
or unit tests which provoke each of the four exceptions.

Summarize this as: "do we *need* to exhaustively cover all failure modes?"

Here's another concern.
The `description` parameter is helpful to humans.
I'm sad that we didn't wrap the original `err` exception.
That is, we've discarded traceback details like the
function and source line number that triggered the DB error.

Maybe a single exception type makes sense, because
all your callers have similar try / except behavior?
But consider creating four child exception classes,
so callers can catch just "the **one** thing" they know
how to recover from, if they want to.

Final concern is very minor.
We offer a maintainer a little less diagnostic
advice in the InFailedSqlTransaction case.
Maybe remedy that by tacking on a `# comment` in that list of four.

---

This code achieves its design objectives.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance
tasks on this codebase.

Comment: Thank you for this thoughtful feedback.

Comment: _I'm just wondering if psycopg2 maybe offers some umbrella exception that you would also like to throw in there_ is correct: I would collapse all of these to `psycopg2.DatabaseError`

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

from psycopg2.errors import DatabaseError


class DomainSpecificException(Exception):
    pass


@contextmanager
def raise_on_insert(table_name: str) -> None:
    try:
        yield
    except DatabaseError as err:
        raise DomainSpecificException(description=f'Failed to insert into: {table_name} because {type(err).__name__}') from err
```

Comment: `from err`, please